# How is this valid Python syntax?

Tags: python

The following is part of SqlAlchemy, I'm trying to figure out how this is valid Python syntax.  I know the code works, I'm just trying to understand what is is doing here and how that is valid.  These are NOT nested classes, they are stand alone classes.  I would have expected a pass after each class declaration though and I'm pretty sure it not being there is significant.

```
class InstrumentedList(list):
    """An instrumented version of the built-in list."""


class InstrumentedSet(set):
    """An instrumented version of the built-in set."""


class InstrumentedDict(dict):
    """An instrumented version of the built-in dict."""


__canned_instrumentation = {
    list: InstrumentedList,
    set: InstrumentedSet,
    dict: InstrumentedDict,
}

__interfaces = {
    list: (
        {'appender': 'append', 'remover': 'remove',
         'iterator': '__iter__'}, _list_decorators()
    ),

    set: ({'appender': 'add',
           'remover': 'remove',
           'iterator': '__iter__'}, _set_decorators()
          ),

    # decorators are required for dicts and object collections.
    dict: ({'iterator': 'values'}, _dict_decorators()) if util.py3k
    else ({'iterator': 'itervalues'}, _dict_decorators()),
}
```

Comment: so what exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: The class body has to contain something, but a docstring counts as that something. It's a statement, like pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid python syntax as long as there is *something* inside of the class definition.

For example:

```
class FooBar:
    """ foobar """
```

This is okay because there is something (in this case a docstring, which can be accessed with the `__doc__` attribute) in the class definition.

However, a class definition without anything in it is invalid syntax:

```
class FooBar:
```

When this is run, it produces the output:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: I guess I'm still thinking about comments like C/C++ as things that aren't code.  I have a new appreciation for docstrings now.